# Multiple drawers Unable to open Right drawer

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-navigation-v6

So I used this implementation based on react navigation V6 [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/multiple-drawers/)
react navigation V6 [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/multiple-drawers/) is weird, so basically we have to
a LeftDrawer then make the LeftDrawer a RightDrawer.Screen. However I do not want to have the LeftDrawer as a screen inside my RightDrawer.

currently I am options using the below to hide it but I wish there is a better solution

```
   options={{
          drawerLabel: () => null,
          title: null,
          drawerIcon: () => null,
        }}
```